# Xcode 11.4 compile error 'unknown option: -platform_version'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11.4

After I updated my MBP to 10.15.4 and Xcode 11.4.1 , the build error disappear.
Still no idea.

---

My project runs well in Xcode 11.3.1. When I update Xcode to 11.4, I got this error when build.

[image]

I deleted derived data and rebuild, the error still exist.

I have no idea where is wrong, can anybody give me some suggestion?

Here is some infomation about my project:

- Using both Objective-C and Swift
- Using Cocoapods (v1.9.1)

More build out below:
Ld /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.app/Mars normal x86_64 (in target 'Mars' from project 'Mars')
    cd /Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMKLocaleDescription -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APNumberPad -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CYLTabBarController -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ClusterKit -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaLumberjack -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DAAlertController -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DZNEmptyDataSet -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FDFullscreenPopGesture -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GPUImage -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GVUserDefaults -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IGListDiffKit -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IGListKit -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManager -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JXCategoryView -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LEEAlert -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MGSwipeTableCell -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MJRefresh -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Masonry -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MessageThrottle -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QMUIKit -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Qiniu -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImageWebPCoder -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SVProgressHUD -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SensorsAnalyticsSDK -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YHExplorer -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YH_Analytics -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YH_AntiCrash -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YH_Lumberjack -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YYKit -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/hpple -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libwebp -L/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/pop -L/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/BaiduMapKit/BaiduMapKit/thirdlibs -L/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/Realm/core -L/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/WechatOpenSDK/OpenSDK1.8.7 -L/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/Weibo_SDK/libWeiboSDK -L/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Dependencies/TXUploadSDK/COSSDK -F/Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/BMKLocationKit/framework -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/BaiduMapKit/BaiduMapKit -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/Bugly -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/LookinServer -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/dynamic -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/UMCAnalytics -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/UMCCommon -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods/WoodPeckeriOS -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Dependencies/QQSDK -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Player -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Dependencies/TXVideoSDK -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Dependencies/TXUploadSDK/COSSDK -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Mars/Dependencies -F/Users/haizi/Mars/Mars_Repo/Mars/Pods -filelist /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mars.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mars_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -flto=thin -Xlinker -cache_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/LTOCache -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mars.swiftmodule -ObjC -lAFNetworking -lAMKLocaleDescription -lAPNumberPad -lCYLTabBarController -lClusterKit -lCocoaLumberjack -lDAAlertController -lDZNEmptyDataSet -lFDFullscreenPopGesture -lGPUImage -lGVUserDefaults -lIGListDiffKit -lIGListKit -lIQKeyboardManager -lJXCategoryView -lLEEAlert -lMBProgressHUD -lMGSwipeTableCell -lMJRefresh -lMasonry -lMessageThrottle -lQMUIKit -lQiniu -lRealm -lSDWebImage -lSDWebImageWebPCoder -lSVProgressHUD -lSensorsAnalyticsSDK -lWeChatSDK -lWeiboSDK -lYHExplorer -lYH_Analytics -lYH_AntiCrash -lYH_Lumberjack -lYYKit -lc++ -lcrypto -lhpple -licucore -llibwebp -lpop -lrealmcore-ios -lsqlite3 -lsqlite3.0 -lssl -lxml2 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework BMKLocationKit -framework BaiduMapAPI_Base -framework BaiduMapAPI_Cloud -framework BaiduMapAPI_Map -framework BaiduMapAPI_Search -framework BaiduMapAPI_Utils -framework Bugly -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework LookinServer -framework MapKit -framework Mapbox -framework MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework Photos -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UMAnalytics -framework UMCommon -framework WebKit -framework WoodPeckeriOS -ObjC -fuse-ld=/usr/local/bin/zld -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.build/Mars.app-Simulated.xcent -framework Accelerate -lsqlite3 -lc++ -framework QCloudCore -framework QCloudCOSXML -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework VideoToolbox -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreMedia -liconv -lz -lbz2 -framework SGPlatform -framework Photos -framework AVFoundation -lresolv -framework CoreMotion -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework TXLiteAVSDK_UGC -lmtasdk -lsqlite3.0 -framework TencentOpenAPI -framework SGPlayer -lPods-abstract_Mars-Mars -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Mars.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Mars_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/haizi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mars-erthhpbohmypyefsgyzfzkwzeakm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mars.app/Mars

Comment: Please show text, not a picture, and show more of it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted more compile output info in my question